# Proving the minimal polynomial of $\text{ann}(T)$ is $p(x)^m$ where $p(x)$ irreducible and $T$ an indecomposable operator on a vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand a proof of the following theorem:

> $(\star)$ Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T$ an indecomposable operator on $V$. Then $T$ is a cyclic operator and the minimal polynomial $\mu_T(x)$ of $T$ is $p(x)^m$ where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial.

In order to prove that $\mu_T(x) = p(x)^m$ where $p(x)$ irreducible, we apply the following:

> Assume $\mu_T(x) = f(x) g(x)$ where $\gcd(f(x),g(x))=1$. Then $\ker(f(T))= \text{range}(g(T))$ and $\ker(g(T))= \text{range}(f(T))$. Moreover, $V= \ker(f(T)) \oplus \ker(g(T))$.

which I proved, but I am having trouble seeing why this implies $\mu_T(x) = p(x)^m$ in $(\star)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\mu_T(x) = f(x)g(x)$ where $f,g$ are monic and $\gcd(f(x),g(x)) = 1$. Then $V = \ker(f(T)) \oplus \ker(g(T))$ and both $\ker(f(T))$ and $\ker(g(T))$ are $T$-invariant. Since $T$ is indecomposable, this decomposition must be trivial. Up to renaming $f$ and $g$, we can assume that $\ker(g(T)) = \{ 0 \}$ and $\ker(f(T)) = V$ but then $f(T) = 0$ hence $\mu_T | f$ which implies that $\mu_T = f$ and $g = 1$.

Now, factor $\mu_T(x)$ as $\mu_T(x) = f_1(x)^{m_1} \ldots f_k(x)^{m_k}$ where $f_i$ are monic, irreducible and distinct and $m_1 \geq 1$. Let $f(x) = f_1(x)^{m_1}$ and $g(x) = f_2(x)^{m_2} \ldots f_k(x)^{m_k}$. Applying the result above, we get that $\mu_T = f$ and $g = 1$ (so $m_2 = \ldots = m_k = 0$). Note that no renaming is needed here because we assumed that $\deg f \geq 1$.

Comment: I'm giving you some extra bounty because you've been helping me so much. All your answers have been very clear, thank you

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, I'm glad to be of help!